# Nginx reverse proxy works on WAN but not LAN

Tags: networking, server, proxy, nginx

I've seen a lot of questions in a lot of places with the *opposite* of this problem, but can't find anything mirroring these results here.

I have a web app that I'm trying to make accessible via my subdomain- let's say service.ilovepuppies.com.

I have it hosted with nodejs on my home Ubuntu server, and set up a reverse proxy with nginx to redirect http traffic from the subdomain to the host server.

Now the weird part- from WAN connections, everything works fine. Type in service.ilovepuppies.com, and my app loads. From the host server, same thing. Loads fine. From two mobile devices (one iOS, one Android) it works fine whether on cellular data or the LAN connection. But on every Windows and Mac device I've tried so far (2 Windows 10 Pro, 1 MacOS) it fails. It will open (eventually) with just some text, but all script files fail to load with "NS_ERROR_NET_RESET" errors in the browser console. If I flip the Mac device to run off a hotspot, suddenly everything loads. Presumably the same for the Windows machines.

I'm not even sure where to start with this one, but any assistance would be massively appreciated.